# Open JPEG/PNG image in photoshop when downloaded from my website

Tags: php, image, shell

I have a PHP web application running where admin can download the image files submitted by users. Now, I want it in a way that when admin downloads those images into his PC, he should just double click on that image and it should open in Photoshop if installed. 
Is this possible?
Or is there a way to write a psd file out of jpg/png file?
I'm looking forward for your answers.

Thanks

Comment: I'm fairly sure that's a PC specific thing, you could try using .psd files for the image format instead, they default to photoshop

Comment: That's up to the user's machine.  The user will need to set up his/her machine and/or browser to open .psd files with Photoshop.

Comment: can we write a psd file in php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load a JPEG file using the PHP [ImageMagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.readimage.php) extension and send it [as PSD](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimageformat.php) to the browser with its [MIME](http://filext.com/file-extension/PSD) type.

I believe the PSD support is always available in ImageMagick, but check it out; I might be wrong.

Then, the browser must know to reroute that file to PhotoShop. It is likely that the PhotoShop installation already instructs it that way, but you may also need to configure the browser instead.

```
$image = new Imagick();

$image->readImage("myImage.jpg");

$image->setImageFormat('psd');
header('Content-type: image/photoshop');
die($image);
```

A really **dirty** way of doing things is to "define" your own MIME type:

```
$jpeg = 'test.jpg';

Header('Content-Type: application/jpeg-with-photoshop');
Header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($jpeg);
readfile($jpeg);
```

The browser will, the first time, pop up a windows saying "WTF? What do I do with a jpeg-with-photoshop file?!?". Just click "Open With > Choose Application > Find application on disk > clickety clickety click > Photoshop" and the browser will remember, and always open what is really a JPEG file by launching Photoshop. Photoshop will then recognize the object as a JPEG file and open it properly.

Comment: It is an image manipulation package for PHP. You will find more info at http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php . Most PHP hosting services supply ImageMagick by default, sometimes you have to ask for it; you can see the output of your phpinfo() to see whether Magick is among the installed modules or not.

Comment: can I use it with my WAMP/APACHE ?

Comment: Yes, surely. There is a distribution for Windows too, you can download the various packages from php.net .

Comment: thank you soo much, I have set up imageMagick and working fine for me.