# Edit image in photoshop from codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

On button click Open image in photoshop from my codeigniter website and can also edit image and save it into folder.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Show you code and effort??

Comment: If I dont have photoshop, does it need to install photoshop ?

Comment: Till now i have't coded anything, just did R & D on google, but got noting.
except one thing, 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120490/open-jpeg-png-image-in-photoshop-when-downloaded-from-my-website

Comment: if u  dont have photoshop than , display just error message : 
" Please Install Photoshop."
For that i have to check , whether  photoshop is insataled in system or not.

Comment: Fairly certain this can't be done.  Unless you're using ActiveX or something like it, you won't have access to that level of system information.

Comment: Ok @Chad , Thank you for guide me in right way.